# Standard or non-standard notation for a function not being dependent on a specific variable.

Tags: functions, logic, notation

Is there a standard or non-standard notation for a function not being dependent on a specific variable. For example, if a function depends on $t$ (time), we denote it $f(t)$. On the other hand, is there a way to express in symbols that $f$ does not vary with $t$? Something like $\forall t_1:\forall t_2: f(t_1)=f(t_2),$ but that logical statement written more compactly.

Comment: p.s. $f(\neg t)$ seems too clunky.

Comment: In some cases it might be appropriate to say $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = 0$.

Comment: Ah, good point. If I had to I could use $\partial _t f=0$

Comment: @AndrewDynneson If the functions you are working with are sufficiently smooth (and the domain is connected), then that is probably what you should do.

Comment: In almost every case in the forseeable future this would do. It would be nice if there was a general logic notation for it.

Comment: Variable, as you are thinking of it, not as a placeholder for a quantifier and not as a register in a program, but rather in the scientific sense like temperature or distance, isn't a defined concept in the major ecosystem of current formal mathematics.  A formal, sound, non burdensome set of formal rules for a system of variables is something that is sorely lacking, and your best bet for finding such things might actually be in literature formalizing science rather than exclusively mathematical literature.

Comment: @DanielV you are saying that you don't think there is a notation for dealing with variables in this way in pure mathematics? Do you think there might be something in science that does this?

Comment: In *language* a standard term is "constant". e.g. "$f(x,y)$ is constant with respect to $x$". Or for your univariate example, "$f$ is a constant function".

Comment: @AndrewDynneson Yes and yes, emphasis on the the might.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, if you didn't want a function to depend on a variable, you simply wouldn't write it as a function of that variable. However, if it turned out a function didn't depend on a variable even though that was not a priori obvious, you could write $f(x,y) = g(x)$ to indicate that, introducing a new function that's explicitly independent of the variable ($y$ in this case).

Comment: This does make sense that it would make that relationship explicit. However, for example, flux $\Phi =LI$, and $L$ depends only on the geometry of the object and does not vary in time, however $I$ is different at different points in time, and I want to make this explicit in mathematical notation, and ideally I would want to use the same symbol $L$, something like "$L$ does not vary with $t$," but in notation.

Comment: Informal mathematical notation is very ambiguous about scope and dependency information. If you are making a (semi-)formal calculus for manipulating such expressions, you probably want to be a lot less ambiguous than typical mathematical notation. If you aren't, then even just writing out "$L$ is independent of/constant with respect to $t$" seems like it wouldn't be that burdensome.

Comment: I know, I just personally write everything in mathematical symbols, often I keep notes on small book margins. I get really into notation.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I can get to saying that $f$ does not vary with $t$ is:
 $$\{f[\neg t] \}:=\{\forall t,t'\in T: f(t)=f(t') \}\supset \{\partial _tf=0\} \equiv \{\dot f=0\}$$

Where $T$ is understood as the set containing that variable. In most cases, the derivative being zero is enough and if the function can be differentiated, then this implies it is a constant with respect to that variable. Hopefully someone can point me to a notation that is better than $f[\neg t]$.